# Why gets the spring bean initialized twice

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, applicationcontext

Spring (mvc) 4.0.3, java 1.7.0_71, tomcat 7.0.57, windows 7

I have a Spring MVC application, with 2 applicationContexts, the applicationContextRoot is loaded with:

```
AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer: protected Class<?>[]  getRootConfigClasses {
    return new Class<?>[] { AppConfig.class }
}
```

The WebApplicationContext is loaded with.

```
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] {WebMvcConfig.class};
}
```

The AppConfig class contains the bean definition for the Bean in focus (Dropwizard's `MetricRegistry`)

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    ...
    @Bean
    public MetricRegistry metricRegistry() {
        MetricRegistry result = new MetricRegistry();
        LOG.info("testing", new Exception("trace me"));
        configureReporters(result);
        return result;
}
```

I see the `trace me stacktrace` called twice. The stacktraces are different:

```
....zipped
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) [spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
```

versus (few msecs later).

```
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) [spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658) [spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:530) [spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484) [spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136) [spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
> at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) [servlet-api.jar:3.0.FR]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1090) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5231) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5518) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.57]
```

The first time the bean is created in the `web.context.ContextLoader` context whereas 2nd time its created in the `web.servlet.FrameworkServlet`
web.xml is empty apart from security constraints, the initialization is done via an instance of `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`

I'm not sure of the impact of this behaviour, but its not what I would expect (beans being singleton etc). Also this behavior remains if I take out every `@autowired` annotation to this bean. I did check that there is only one @componentscan (in WebMvcConfig)

Comment: It sounds like you're component scanning in `WebMvcConfig` but not excluding `Configuration` classes. e.g. `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"mypackage"}, excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Configuration.class))`

Comment: @beerbajay thanks a ton! If you make it an answer I will award it.

Comment: This can occur if you have more than one DispatcherServlet as well, as multiple Contexts are created from the classes returned by `getServletConfigClasses()`. If there is truly only one DispatcherServlet, then returning all of the Configuration classes from Root can solve this problem as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're component scanning in `WebMvcConfig` but not excluding Configuration classes.

You can do this with:

```
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = {"mypackage"}, 
    excludeFilters = 
        @ComponentScan.Filter(
            type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, 
            value = Configuration.class
        )
)
```